# Static variable for function returning a reference

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, global-variables, static-variables

I have a map-like structure that returns zero when it can't find an element in the container.
Since the access is immutable it makes sense to return a const reference, 
both when the element is found in the map and when the element is not found.

```
#include<map>
#include<cassert>

struct M{
    std::map<int, double> vals;
    double const& operator[](int i) const{
        static double const zero = 0.0; // static variable in function
        auto f = vals.find(i);
        if(f == vals.end()) return zero;
        return f->second;
    }
};

int main(){
    M m; m.vals = {{1, 11.}, {3, 33.}};
    assert( m[2] == 11. );
    assert( m[2] == 0. );
    assert( m[3] == 33. );
}
```

But then I though that maybe it is better to attach the zero value to the object. 
For a little memory (one per instance) I could make zero "more local" to the referenced object (`m`).

```
struct M{
    std::map<int, double> vals;
    private:
    double const zero = 0.0; // m
    public:
    double const& operator[](int i) const{
        auto f = vals.find(i);
        if(f == vals.end()) return zero;
        return f->second;
    }
};
```

**Which option is better?** In terms of correctness and flexibility.

Things to take into account are (at least) memory, threads and time of access.

This reminds me of this talk in which it was proposed to reimplement `std::string` in such a way the terminating character '\0' was a global object instead of part of the memory of each string. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPR8h4-qZdk

---

As a matter of fact, with the appropriate modified copy constructor there is a whole family possible implementations (5 more at least) that are semantically equivalent:

```
static const double zero = 0.0; // free static variable
struct M{
    std::map<int, double> vals;
    double const& operator[](int i) const{
        auto f = vals.find(i);
        if(f == vals.end()) return zero;
        return f->second;
    }
};

static constexpr double zero = 0.0; // static constexpr
struct M{
    std::map<int, double> vals;
    double const& operator[](int i) const{
        auto f = vals.find(i);
        if(f == vals.end()) return zero;
        return f->second;
    }
};

struct M{
    std::map<int, double> vals;
    double const& operator[](int i) const{
        static constexpr double zero = 0.0; // static constexpr in function
        auto f = vals.find(i);
        if(f == vals.end()) return zero;
        return f->second;
    }
};

struct M{
    std::map<int, double> vals;
    static constexpr double zero = 0.0; // static member constexpr
    double const& operator[](int i) const{
        auto f = vals.find(i);
        if(f == vals.end()) return zero;
        return f->second;
    }
};

struct M{
    std::map<int, double> vals;
    static const double zero; // static const member
    double const& operator[](int i) const{
        auto f = vals.find(i);
        if(f == vals.end()) return zero;
        return f->second;
    }
};
const double M::zero = 0.0;
```

---

Finally, after a suggestion by @StoryTeller there is an extra option that is to return by value:

```
struct M{
    std::map<int, double> vals;
    double operator[](int i) const{
        auto f = vals.find(i);
        if(f == vals.end()) return 0;
        return f->second;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why not `if (f == vals.end()) return 0;`?

Comment: What if `0` is in the map?

Comment: Why not just return by value?

Comment: @Rakete1111, is `0` is in the keys of the map it will return `val[0]`, if `0` is not in the keys it will return `0.0`.

Comment: @feareoc, in `gcc` I get `warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
    return 0;`. I suspect it is a temporary and it is not correct. Even if it is correct, in generic cases I will be constructing an object instead of returning a ready constructed one.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I guess to avoid copies. In this case it doesn't make a difference to return `double` or `double const&`, what if the mapped type is not double but something costly to copy.

Comment: @alfC not sure about it, but `auto f` is a copy of `vals.find(i)`, not a reference. `auto& f` would be, but I am not sure about its lifetime, that is if you can safely return it

Comment: @feareoc, find returns an iterator, it is ok to copy an iterator (it is not copying the value). It is not the point of the question. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find . The code without `auto` would be `std::map<int, double>::const_iterator f = vals.find(i);`. The point is that I have to return `f->second` which is a reference to double if the entry is found.

Comment: @alfC - That's kinda self contradicting. Not all types have a "default" value either.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I meant "what if the mapped type is not double but something costly to construct.". I don't understand your comment. Whether the type has a default value is irrelevant, the point is that `zero` is a specific constant value. What is self contradicting?

Comment: @alfC `zero` is a default value for type `double`. You cannot `return 0` for a custom type, e.g. `const Foo&`

Comment: It's self contradiction to talk about the "generic case" and types that are "costly to construct", when ignoring that generally, not all types have a "zero".

Comment: What you could do is to throw an error instead: `if (f == vals.end()) throw "Index not found";` or even create your own error class. It is a bit of a hassle to always have to make a try and catch when accessing but it would work, e.g. `try { std::cout << m[3] << std::endl; } catch (const char* e) { std::cout << "Error: " << e << std::endl; }`

Comment: @StoryTeller,  suppose that one has `template<class T> struct M{
    std::map<int, T> vals;
    T const& operator[](int i) const{
        static T const magic{}; 
        auto f = vals.find(i);
        if(f == vals.end()) return magic;
        return f->second;
    }
};`. Do you suggest to do this instead `T operator[](int i) const{
        auto f = vals.find(i);
        if(f == vals.end()) return T{};
        return f->second;
    }`? Wouldn't that make an unnecessary temporary of `T`? What is the construction is costly? (ok, default ctr shouldn't be costly).

Comment: That would not compile for any `T` that does not have a default constructor

Comment: @feareoc, of course, it is a requirement for this code that `T` has a default constructor. It will work only for `T`s that have a default constructor. The question still hold. Which option to use? (assuming that `T` is default constructible).

Comment: That is a bold requirement. In my opinion, returning a default value isn't a good option, since there would be a confusion between default value returned as a result of missing index or not. Throwing an exception or returning a null pointer would indicate that better

Comment: @feareoc, default construction is a common requirement in many cases (in `std::map` for example). And that is the point, I don't want to make a distintion between a non existent element in the underlying map and a default value.

Comment: In that case, I'd go with return `const T&` and having a `static const T` in the `operator[]` overload. You could also have a non-constant version of the `operator[]` overload in case you'd like to change the value at the index: `T& operator[] (int index);` and `m[<index>] = <value>;`. If you were to return the same default value you could consider making it a static member of the class instead of a static variable in the method.